# Fiware Orion: Using Orion internal mongoDB to store other information

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Could we use Orion internal MongoDB data base to store other information?
For example using Cygnus to persist data in it?
Or should it be dedicated to Orion?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: I don't agree on the flag about opinion-basing. The answer of the question is based on objective facts derived from Orion functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

From a functional point of view, as long as you don't use the same DB that Orion uses (by default `orion`) or (in the case of using `-multiservice`) the DB used by individual tenants (by default, the ones starting with `orion-` prefix) there shouldn't be any conflict.

From a non functional point of view, you should check that the MongoDB instance (or cluster) is sized properly to support the aggregated load combining all the applications using it (Orion and others).